When does assigning the return value result in a copy?
There are six lines in int main below where a variable is being created and initialized; in which (if any) of these scenarios does a copy get created for the assignment?
Additionally, in the case of sixthMap, does/could anything weird happen, since we're using automatic deduction with an ampersand but the function it's calling also returns a reference?
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>
createStdObject()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector> newUnorderedMap
    {
        {"A", {"first", "vector", "in", "map"}, 
        {"B", {"second", "vector", "in", "map"}
    };

    return newUnorderedMap;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>&
createStdObjectWithReference()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector> newUnorderedMap
    {
        {"A", {"first", "vector", "in", "map"}, 
        {"B", {"second", "vector", "in", "map"}
    };

    return newUnorderedMap;
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector> firstMap = newUnorderedMap();
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector> secondMap = createStdObjectWithReference();
    
    const auto thirdMap = newUnorderedMap();
    const auto& fourthMap = newUnorderedMap();

    const auto fifthMap = createStdObjectWithReference();
    const auto& sixthMap = createStdObjectWithReference();
    
}


What I would guess - based on my limited knowledge - is:

firstMap and thirdMap could be copies of the return value of newUnorderedMap()
All of the others would not result in copies, but a move/swap
The ampersand in the auto declaration of sixthMap would essentially be ignored, and sixthMap would be identical to fifthMap in terms of type and behaviour

On the other hand, it is obvious at compile time itself that none of the return values actually need to be copied, and as such I see no reason why they shouldn't all result in a move assignment

Copy elision can eliminate copies in many cases (see the link for more info).

createStdObjectWithReference() is UB. You can't return a reference to a local automatic variable. A decent compiler should give you a warning when compiled with the correct options. auto never deduces a reference type, so 5th and 6th are not equivalent. To deduce a reference type you need to use decltype(auto). Not writing a full answer because this contains multiple questions in one and each of them is a duplicate.

createStdObjectWithReference is UB. It returns a dangling pointer. Any decent IDE can catch this type of bug. Most compilers would diagnose it. More over, your initializer lists lack a couple of closing brackets.

It would also be nice if your code actually compiled.

Trick question: there are no assignments in the program! Those = signs are not assignment operators.

Ignoring that your code has a lot of, what I assume are, typing errors, what you fail to understand is one of the most fundamental concepts in C++: object lifetime. To explain it briefly in an unprecise way (for the sake of understanding):
Every object created on the stack (i.e. locally) has its scope (you can recognize a scope by curly braces). Once that scope is exited, all the objects that were created in that scope are destroyed. Furthermore, each function is also a scope, which means that each object created in a function stops existing once the end of the function is reached. Therefore, the only way for objects created inside a function to "outlive" the function is if they are copied/moved to some address external to the function.
What might seem like an exception is this thing called copy-elision. When your function returns by value, and the returned object was created in that function, there will be no copy/move involved and it would seem like your newly created object escaped its scope. However, in reality, your object was actually created on the call site, outside of the scope of that function, while function is used only to initialize that already created object. This is what copy-elision means, roughly. It boils down to copying a pointer, but no constructor is invoked. Note, however, that the Standard does not guarantee this to happen yet, but, for all practical purposes, it is what happens.
Therefore, the following code:
#include <cstdio>
class Lifetime
{
  public:
    Lifetime() { std::puts("default ctor"); }
    Lifetime(Lifetime&&) { std::puts("move ctor"); }
    Lifetime(const Lifetime&) { std::puts("copy ctor"); }
    ~Lifetime() { std::puts("destructor"); }
};

Lifetime make_lifetime() {
    Lifetime l{}; // Lifetime object initialized
    return l; // Lifetime object not destroyed because created outside the function scope
}

const Lifetime& make_lifetime_ref() {
    Lifetime l{}; // Lifetime object created
    return l;     // Lifetime object destroyed
}

int main() {
    const auto lifetime1 = make_lifetime(); // Lifetime object created; copy ctor not called!

    // 'make_lifetime_ref' returns a reference to already destroyed object
    // const auto lifetime2 = make_lifetime_ref(); // oops! undefined behaviour:

    return 0;
}

would produce this output:
$ default ctor
$ destructor

As you can see, there is no copying involved.
Note that auto has nothing to do with any of this, i.e. it will not affect copying. So, in your case, the creation of firstMap, thirdMap and fourthMap would not involve copying, while the other three would cause undefined behavior. Also note that this is all relating to local variables, others have a bit different rules.

This is not entirely correct. NRVO is not guaranteed by the standard (any version so far). In your case a standard-conforming compiler have two choices for the lifetime1 = make_lifetime();: it can perform a move, or it can do NRVO and construct the object in place. Your compiler chose the second and I doubt any reasonable compiler would fail to do NRVO for such a simple case, but it is not guaranteed by the standard. On the other hand, if the function body of make_lifetime() is just return Lifetime{};, then since C++17 no copy or move is allowed.

@WeijunZhou Correct me if I am wrong, but P2025R0 made it into C++23. Nonetheless, I have explicitly stated that my answer is not very precise but I regard it as justified since the OP obviously has knowledge gaps in the most fundamental concepts. It would be preposterous to throw all the details at him.

I don't think P2025 is accepted. I cannot see the proposed wording in the latest draft, and the corresponding issue is still an open one (It would have been plenary-approved along with a c++ standard tag if accepted). I also don't mean that you need to cover all the details, just a kind reminder that the standard doesn't guarantee that or the standard also allows moving would be enough. Anyway now you get a +1 from me.

@WeijunZhou Ah, I thought it was accepted for some reason. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Ah, of course createStdObjectWithReference would return an address to an object of type std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>, and since the object is within the scope of the function the returned pointer would of course be unbound. What an incredibly stupid thing of me to miss

The remaining, valid parts of my question are answered by NRVO - something that I hadn't heard of up to now - and the comment by @WeijunZhou that auto never deduces a reference type.
Thanks!! And apologies for the carelessness in formulating the question

@Numinous No worries, I am glad I could help. This is, in my opinion at least, what the stack overflow is for.
